# Why when all values x in set A and x is part of set B, A is a subset of B?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Reading an intro to `mathematical sets` I stumbled on one property that I don't see the logic of:

If $\forall{x} \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$, then A is called a *subset* of B ($A \subset B$).

The way I read this is: when every value of `x` is in the set `A`, and one value of `x` is also in set `B` - all values of `A` are present in the set `B`. But this doesn't make sense:

1. $x$ may not be the only kind of value in $A$
2. a single value of $x$ can't be equal to $\forall{x}$

What am I missing/misinterpreting?

Comment: are you really sure it is called superset?

Comment: Thanks for fixing me, indeed it was supposed to be a _subset_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is probably intended is $\forall x\left(x\in A\longrightarrow x\in B\right)$. The parentheses are very important.

This means that any $x$ that is in $A$ is in $B$. But then $A$ is a **subset** of $B$, or equivalently, $B$ is a **superset** of $A$.

Comment: I do understand your version of the notation as intended, so then to add to my question: is there something wrong with the original notation in my question or am I just reading it wrong?

Comment: Yes, the notation used, if you are quoting verbatim, is quite bad. The universal quantifier is being misused. One has to guess what is intended. And writing $A$ is a superset of $B$ and at the same time writing $A\subseteq B$ is absolutely wrong.

Comment: The statement about A being a _superset_ was my typo (fixed now). Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @MorganWilde $\forall x\in A$ is not a statement, it is just a (bounded) quantifier. You could write your statement in the form $\forall x\in A\,(x\in B)$: "For all $x\in A$, it holds that $x\in B$". But this is just an abbreviation for the longish formula André has provided.

Answer (score 2):

$x$ is not a variable here. It is just a particular element belonging to the set $A$. What the definition of subset actually says is that, every element that is contained in $A$ has to be contained in $B$. For example if $1$ belongs to $A$ then $1$ belongs to $B$.

Answer (score 2):

You should read it this way:

If every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$, then $A$ is a subset of $B$.